# How to get the Collation of string Fields in a Result Set via SqlDataReader?

Tags: .net, sql-server, collation, sqldatareader, sqlclr

When retrieving a Result Set from a [SqlDataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader), it is possible to get most of the meta-data for that Result Set by using the [GetSchemaTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataReader_GetSchemaTable) method. One thing that is missing, however, is the Collation of the string fields (i.e. `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, `NCHAR`, `NVARCHAR`, `SQL_VARIANT` – if containing a string type – and even the deprecated `TEXT` and `NTEXT`). Is there any way at all to get this info?

While it is technically possible to call the [GetSqlString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getsqlstring#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataReader_GetSqlString_System_Int32_) method which has the `LCID` and `SqlCompareOptions` properties, those properties return the values related to the default Collation of the *Database*, which may or may not be the Collation of any particular field (even though most people seem to just assume that it is the same) or expression (due to [Collation Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collation-precedence-transact-sql)). Those properties only provide accurate info when the source data type is `SQL_VARIANT`, which is not terribly helpful.

The problem with not having this extra info (at the very least the "LCID" which equates to the Locale) is that while all characters, regardless of source encoding, can be represented in .NET without loss (since .NET strings are UTF-16 Little Endian), it is impossible to determine what Locale to use when comparing fields in the result set to other strings.

The Collation info, per each string field, is definitely part of the [result set meta-data](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParserHelperClasses.cs,818) sent to the client from SQL Server via the TDS stream. It is used:

- to expose the `LCID` via the [GetLocaleId](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlDataReader.cs,1282) method of the `SqlDataReader` class. But that method is marked `internal` so I don't have access to it. It seems to only be used in one place: [SqlBulkCopy](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlBulkCopy.cs,748).
- to provide the Result Set structure to the [Send(SqlDataReader)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/Microsoft/SqlServer/Server/sqlpipe.cs,118) method of `SqlPipe`, which is used in SQLCLR Stored Procedures and Triggers.
- to set the proper `encoding`, depending on circumstances, in the [GetTextReader()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlDataReader.cs,1870) method of `SqlDataReader`. However, while that method is `public`, the `TextReader` class does not have a property for `Encoding`; the encoding info was only used internally.

**UPDATE**

To clarify: the desire is to have a means of getting this information that does not require the Assembly to be Fully Trusted / `UNSAFE`. The intended use is code that runs in both a Console App as well as SQLCLR objects (Stored Procedures, Functions, etc). If the Assembly (when loaded into SQL Server) is required to have a `PERMISSION_SET` of `EXTERNAL_ACCESS`, that would be acceptable. But requiring the SQLCLR Assembly to be marked as `UNSAFE` will not work.

The ultimate supreme ideal would be getting the full Collation name as it exists in SQL Server (e.g. `Latin1_General_100_BIN2`), *and* with the Assembly, within SQL Server, being marked as `SAFE`.

**UPDATE 2**

Using Reflection, as per @Jonathan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35191462/577765), it is possible to invoke the "internal" `GetLocaleId` method, and it does return the correct LCID. However, when using this code in a SQLCLR object, it will get the following exception if the Assembly is not marked as `UNSAFE`:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "GetFieldCollation":
>
> System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by method 'UserDefinedFunctions.GetFieldCollation(System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString, System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBoolean)' to access method 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetLocaleId(Int32)' failed.
>
> System.MethodAccessException:
>   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.PerformSecurityCheck(Object obj, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal method, RuntimeType parent, UInt32 invocationFlags)
>   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.PerformSecurityCheck(Object obj, IRuntimeMethodInfo method, RuntimeType parent, UInt32 invocationFlags)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)

Looking at this MSDN article, [Walkthrough: Emitting Code in Partial Trust Scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/walkthrough-emitting-code-in-partial-trust-scenarios), it even mentions (emphasis added):

> **Adding RestrictedMemberAccess to Sandboxed Domains**
> ...
> For example, a host might grant Internet applications Internet permissions plus RMA, so that an Internet application can emit code that accesses private data in its own assemblies. *Because the access is limited to assemblies of equal or lesser trust, an Internet application cannot access members of fully trusted assemblies such as .NET Framework assemblies.*

Unfortunately, requiring the Assembly to be `UNSAFE` goes against the requirements.

And, to be honest, this is really just part of the overall puzzle. As stated in the first UPDATE section, the goal is to have this *and* the true Collation Name, and that does not seem to exist anywhere at the moment. Hence, I sent the following suggestion with Microsoft:

<del>Expose Collation Info of SQL Server Result Set via SqlDataReader</del> (link no longer valid due to visualstudio.uservoice.com being shut down)

**UPDATE 3**

To clarify: *ideally* there would be a method or property that returns the *exact* collation used for a given string field (e.g. `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_KS_WS_SC`). However, merely exposing `LCID` and `SqlCompareOptions` is likely not good enough as those properties do not convey the following info:

- collation version (currently 80 (i.e. unspecified), 90, 100, or 140 / or even the alternate 0, 1, 2, or 3 would be good enough)
- `_BIN` vs `_BIN2`
- `CodePage`
- `_VSS` (Variation Selector Sensitive; starting in SQL Server 2017 via the Japanese version 140 collations)
- `_SC` (Supplementary Character Aware -- i.e. allowing built-in functions to deal with `NVARCHAR` data as UTF-16 instead of UCS-2)
- SQL Server collation vs Windows collation
- SortID (only used for SQL Server collations)
- `_UTF8` (UTF-8 encoding for `VARCHAR` data; new in SQL Server 2019)

At bare minimum the additional info sent in the Tabular Data Stream (TDS) needs to be exposed. That info is:

- collation version (currently 80 (i.e. unspecified), 90, 100, or 140 / or even the alternate 0, 1, 2, or 3 would be good enough)
- `_BIN` vs `_BIN2`
- SortID (only used for SQL Server collations)
- `_UTF8` (UTF-8 encoding for `VARCHAR` data; new in SQL Server 2019)

The SortID, because it's only used for SQL Server collations, gets us:

- SQL Server collation vs Windows collation

The SortID or LCID (depending on type of collation), can be used to derive:

- `CodePage`

That still leaves the following options currently unaccounted for:

- `_VSS` (Variation Selector Sensitive; starting in SQL Server 2017 via the Japanese version 140 collations)
- `_SC` (Supplementary Character Aware -- i.e. allowing built-in functions to deal with `NVARCHAR` data as UTF-16 instead of UCS-2)

So, perhaps this is not technically possible at the moment, but I figured I would ask just in case there was something I was missing. It just seems quite odd to me that this info isn't already available.

Answer (score 1):

You can access internal property easily with reflection or expression tree (for performance)

```
var method = typeof (SqlDataReader).GetMethod("GetLocaleId", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(My.Config.ConnectionStrings.SqlConnection))
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 0 * FROM TestTable", conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();

            // 1033 = Latin1_General_CI_AS (confirmed)
            var collation2 = method.Invoke(reader, new object[] { 2 });

            // 1048 = Romanian_CI_AS (Current : SQL_Romanian_CP1250_CI_AS, close enough!)
            var collation3 = method.Invoke(reader, new object[] { 3 });
        }
    }
}
```

Collation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143508(v=sql.105).aspx

**Edit**

You can access to all internal, private or anything else via reflection or expression tree.

You can also use [Eval Expression.NET](http://eval-expression.net/) to make it even more easier!

```
// using Z.Expressions;

var getLocalIdCompiled = Eval.Compile<Func<SqlDataReader, int, int>>("reader.GetLocaleId(value)", "reader", "value");

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(My.Config.ConnectionStrings.SqlConnection))
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 0 * FROM TestTable", conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();

            var collation2 = getLocalIdCompiled(reader, 2);
            var collation3 = getLocalIdCompiled(reader, 3);
        }
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Eval Expression.NET](http://eval-expression.net/)

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks :-). Lemme try it out. Also, is it possible to read an internal and/or private variable in the same manner?

Comment: Jonathan: thanks for that update. I have been able to test the original suggestion and it does work (so +1 for that), but it requires the Assembly (when used in SQLCLR) to be set to UNSAFE. That wasn't an original requirement so I have updated the Question to include it. Also, I will say that if we were expecting a value of 1250 and received 1048, then that would not be close enough ;-). However, the 1048 is the correct answer. The 1250 is the Code Page, not the LCID: `SELECT COLLATIONPROPERTY(N'SQL_Romanian_CP1250_CI_AS', 'LCID')`.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this compiler require unsafe persmission (The one used in  Eval SQL.NET can be run in safe mode but not public for now).

I'm still unsure what's missing to your question. You can get the LCID using reflection (safe permission) and I believe there is no way, you can find collation name without "hardcoding" or doing a database round trip.

Comment: Hi again. I didn't use the compiler. I just did `var method = typeof(SqlDataReader).GetMethod("GetLocaleId", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance); var collation2 = method.Invoke(_Reader, new object[] { 0 });` I thought that was using Reflection? Are you saying that there is a way to run `GetLocaleId` in a `SAFE` Assembly? If so, can you provide an example, please. Sorry, but I haven't done much with Reflection.

Comment: This is reflection and its work in SAFE Assembly. The method in your comment and my first example work to get the "GetLocaleId" value...We for sure doesn’t understand each other on this question ;)

Comment: Then perhaps I am doing something wrong. Do I need to decorate my method with any particular attributes? Loading the assembly works as SAFE, but running the code fails on the call to `Invoke()` with `System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by method '...' to access method 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetLocaleId(Int32)' failed. at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.PerformSecurityCheck(Object obj, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal method, RuntimeType parent, UInt32 invocationFlags)`. I can only get past that exception when setting the Assembly to `UNSAFE`. What am I missing?

Comment: You are right, my bad. I used so much reflection/expression in my SQL CLR that I assumed it was always working. It seem we cannot access to internal value in SAFE && EXTERNAL_ACCESS. It so sick, the value is here but we cannot access it!

Comment: No problem. I'm just glad to know that I am not going crazy ;-). Yes, it is very frustrating that the info is there, almost within reach. I just updated my question with another UPDATE section covering this attempt and a suggestion I posted last night for the Visual Studio/.NET team. Either way, I do appreciate the help on this :-)